# How to iterate over pandas DataFrame multi-index and filtering based off another column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, multi-index

I am trying to do iterate over a multi-index with the following DataFrame.

[Picture of My DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15O7K.png)

Essentially, what I am trying to do is reduce the DataFrame to the top QB, top 2 RB's, top 3 WR's, and top TE based off their values in their respective "FantasyPoints" column for each NFL team. I have been trying to figure out for hours how to do this, but can't come up with a solution. I tried using groupby but no luck, and figured I may have to iterate over the multi-index but haven't figured that out either. Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me figure this out. Below is the code used to generate the DataFrame in its existing state. Here is a link to the CSV file that is being used. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hX1Jmjk4RBxsH8tt8g1tqwKqrjZkFZp_/view?usp=sharing

```
#import our CSV file
df = pd.read_csv('2019.csv')

#drop unneccessary columns
df.drop(['Rk', '2PM', '2PP', 'FantPt', 'DKPt', 'FDPt', 
         'VBD', 'PosRank', 'OvRank', 'PPR', 'Fmb', 
         'GS', 'Age', 'Tgt', 'Y/A', 'Att', 'Att.1', 'Cmp', 'Y/R'], axis=1, inplace=True)

#fix name formatting
df['Player'] = df['Player'].apply(lambda x: x.split('*')[0]).apply(lambda x: x.split('\\')[0])

#rename columns
df.rename({
    'TD': 'PassingTD',
    'TD.1': 'RushingTD',
    'TD.2': 'ReceivingTD',
    'TD.3': 'TotalTD',
    'Yds': 'PassingYDs',
    'Yds.1': 'RushingYDs',
    'Yds.2': 'ReceivingYDs',
}, axis=1, inplace=True)

df['FantasyPoints'] = (df['PassingYDs']*0.04 + df['PassingTD']*4 - df['Int']*2 + df['RushingYDs']*.1 
                       + df['RushingTD']*6 + df['Rec']*1 + df['ReceivingYDs']*.1 + df['ReceivingTD']*6 - df['FL']*2)

df = df[['Tm', 'FantPos', 'FantasyPoints']]

df = df[df['Tm'] != '2TM']
df = df[df['Tm'] != '3TM']

df.set_index(['Tm', 'FantPos'], inplace=True)
df = df.sort_index()
df.head(30)
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to your data? Or put in this question the coded to generate your dataframe?

Comment: Yes, just added a link to CSV file in Google Drive and added the code used to create the DataFrame in its present state.

Comment: The simplest solution would probably be to filter the original dataframe for each category (QB, RB, WR, etc) and then use nlargest for each one. Once you have done this, you should be able to use concatenate to put them back together easily.

Answer (score 0):

Why do multi-index?? You can easily set up a dictionary to iterate through and grab the top n rows for each condition/position:

```
import pandas as pd

#import our CSV file
df = pd.read_csv('2019.csv')

#drop unneccessary columns
df.drop(['Rk', '2PM', '2PP', 'FantPt', 'DKPt', 'FDPt', 
         'VBD', 'PosRank', 'OvRank', 'PPR', 'Fmb', 
         'GS', 'Age', 'Tgt', 'Y/A', 'Att', 'Att.1', 'Cmp', 'Y/R'], axis=1, inplace=True)

#fix name formatting
df['Player'] = df['Player'].apply(lambda x: x.split('*')[0]).apply(lambda x: x.split('\\')[0])

#rename columns
df.rename({
    'TD': 'PassingTD',
    'TD.1': 'RushingTD',
    'TD.2': 'ReceivingTD',
    'TD.3': 'TotalTD',
    'Yds': 'PassingYDs',
    'Yds.1': 'RushingYDs',
    'Yds.2': 'ReceivingYDs',
}, axis=1, inplace=True)

df['FantasyPoints'] = (df['PassingYDs']*0.04 + df['PassingTD']*4 - df['Int']*2 + df['RushingYDs']*.1 
                       + df['RushingTD']*6 + df['Rec']*1 + df['ReceivingYDs']*.1 + df['ReceivingTD']*6 - df['FL']*2)

df = df[['Tm', 'FantPos', 'FantasyPoints']]

df = df[df['Tm'] != '2TM']
df = df[df['Tm'] != '3TM']


dictionary = {'QB':1,'RB':2,'WR':3,'TE':1}
results_df = pd.DataFrame()
for pos, n in dictionary.items():
    results_df = results_df.append(df[df['FantPos'] == pos].nlargest(n, columns='FantasyPoints'), sort=True).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output:**

print (results_df)

```
  FantPos  FantasyPoints   Tm
0      QB         415.68  BAL
1      RB         469.20  CAR
2      RB         314.80  GNB
3      WR         374.60  NOR
4      WR         274.10  TAM
5      WR         274.10  ATL
6      TE         254.30  KAN
```